# discover another ios device without connecting to common network

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, wifi-direct

I was looking into Multipeer Connectivity Framework trying to find a way of how to connect nearby devices. To be more precise I have two iPhones at my disposal. The idea is to establish connection between them in order to be able to transfer small audio streams. One-to-one connection is enough, there's no need to create groups.

It all works fine and devices can discover each other if I do any of following:

- turn on bluetooth on both devices
- connect them to the same wi-fi network
- manually establish peer-to-peer wi-fi connection between them

But is it possible to somehow discover nearby devices only by having them both wi-fi turned on? Ideally they would "see" each other and create a direct connection.

I'm sorry if question like this was already asked, but it's really hard to formulate what I try to achieve in a sentence and therefore it's not easy to find any info about it.

Comment: You could have them register their locations with a server and use that information to identify devices that are near one another, but this will depend on the location accuracy available which may be low, e.g. Indoors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that just using Bounjour API (`NSNetService` level) makes it really easy:

```
let browser = NSNetServiceBrowser()
browser.includesPeerToPeer = true
```

Ended up taking [this excellent example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple, rewriting parts of it in swift and adapting it to my needs.

Note: I've also tried to make it work with MultipeerConnectivity framework, but it just didn't work. Although devices would discover each other successfully they still couldn't establish a connection. 
And `NSNetService`-based solution works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to send some audio or video files to another apple device, I think you can use airDrop to to this.